# What are the definitions of Time to Peak, Cerebral Blood Flow and Mean Transit Time?

Tags: brain, medical-imaging

I am trying to compute Time to Peak, Cerebral Blood Flow (CBF) and Mean Transit Time (MTT) maps in brain CT imaging. I tried to find the definitions or some articles but I am not from the medical background. Any links or explanation about these terms? I need to get pixel-by-pixel values for each slice for the above three parameters.

I would also like to know the step by step procedure for computing the map images of CBF and Time to Peak or (Cerebral Blood Volume)

Thanks,

Gopi